# if not equal condition in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a condition where the value should not be null or it should be either `R` or `U`.
i had tried with below method but still i am not able to succeed with the result.

```
if (Place == "" || Place != "R" || Place != "U")
   {
    response.Status = "FAILURE";
    response.Message = "Place Criteria is required / Invalid (place should be either R(rural)/U(urban)";
   }
```

eventhough i pass `R` or `U` it shows the error message . please help me with the solution.

Thanks

Comment: `if (Place == "" || Place != "R" || Place != "U")` If I was looking for a city that wasn't Sydney **or** wasn't LA then **every** city will meet that condition. Let's take Sydney as an example. Well, it is Sydney - alas. But it **isn't** LA. And since it is `or` then `false or true` - well, that is true. Now - if you used **and** instead - that would likely do what you want. Since `true and false` is false.

Comment: Hint: try to apply various inputs and think how your condition performs. E.g. assume `Place = "R"`, what you get at the end? `true` or `false`? Is that what you need? No? Then change condition to make "R" working. Repeat.

Comment: If `Place == "R"` is true then `Place != "U"` is true. If `Place == "U"` is true then `Place != "R"` is true.

Comment: What should happen if `Place` is blank? Should it enter the `if` or not?

Comment: if `Place` is blank it should enter @mjwills

Comment: `string[] valid = new string[] {"U", "R"}; if (!valid.Contains(Place)) {response.Status = "FAILURE"; ...}`

Comment: @mjwills yes and also if it is null

Comment: @chethu Take a look at [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epg8V.png) to understand what's wrong.

Comment: `if (Place != "R" && Place != "U")` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Place ==""||( Place!="R" && Place !="U"))
{

}
```

you want the Place not be null and be "R" or "U" so you should use && to make sure the 3(null,"R","U") do not happen at the same time.

Comment: Is the first comparison necessary? What will this code do if `Place` is `R`?

Comment: not necessary it can be removed. I just want to show the comparison to @chethu

Comment: Do note `Null != ""`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `else if` constructon; here we have `2` *valid* options (rural and urban) and all the others are incorrect ones:

```
 if (Place == "R")
   RuralRoutine(); //TODO: put the right code here
 else if (Place == "U")
   UrbanRoutine(); //TODO: put the right code here
 else { // All the other options are invalid
   response.Status = "FAILURE";
   response.Message = 
     "Place Criteria is required / Invalid (place should be either R(rural)/U(urban)";
 }
```

Please, note, that if you want to add, say, `"I"` for an "Industrial Area", all you'll have to do is to add one more `else if`:

```
 ...
 else if (Place == "I")
   IndustrialAreaRoutine();
 else {  
   response.Status = "FAILURE";
   ...
```